# Ensuring Sub-5 Second Failover in Highly Consistent Database Architecture on AWS

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, fault, fault-tolerance, resiliency

I'm seeking guidance on implementing fault tolerance in a database architecture on AWS with a crucial requirement for high data consistency. While numerous strategies emphasize heightened availability, it appears that achieving true fault tolerance involves more than just ensuring availability.

What would be the most effective approach to implement fault tolerance in this context? I've observed that certain AWS strategies boast an average failback time of 13 to 15 seconds. However, my system is mission-critical and demands responses within a 5-second timeframe. What steps and best practices should I follow to ensure prompt fault recovery while maintaining the necessary level of data consistency?

My expectation in formulating the questionis to obtain insights and specific guidance on best practices, strategies, and necessary steps for implementing effective fault tolerance in a database architecture on AWS.